# linked list in linked List in C, segfault at reading in second list

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm writing at a logfile searchprogramm for A Mailserver. I have eine struct with another struct linked inside. My func put the Data of a TimeStamp, a MailserverIp, the specific MailId in a single-linked list. Moreover I have a List of Receivers, which I also wanna put it in a single linked list which is a pointer in the first single-linked-list. (A linked-list inside a linked-list)

The structs I made are the following:

```
struct SearchEntry{
    int headindex;
    char *TimeStamp;
    char *IP;
    struct Empfaenger *nextE;    
    struct Empfaenger *anfangE;  
    char *MailId;
    struct SearchEntry *next;
};

struct Empfaenger{
    int headindex;
    char *Empfaenger;
    struct Empfaenger *nextE;  
};
```

This is the function to put the data inside the two lists:

```
void write_list(char *TimeStamp, char *IP, char *Empfaenger, char *MailId){
    printf("MailID: %s\n", MailId);
    if(anfang==NULL){
        if((anfang=malloc(sizeof(struct SearchEntry)))==NULL){
            fprintf(stderr, "Kein Speicherplatz vorhanden für Anfang\n");
            return;
        }
        printf("starta!\n");
        anfang->TimeStamp=malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(TimeStamp));
        anfang->IP=malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(IP));
        anfang->MailId=malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(MailId));
        strcpy(anfang->TimeStamp, TimeStamp);
        strcpy(anfang->IP, IP);
        strcpy(anfang->MailId, MailId);
        headindexcounter=0;
        anfang->headindex=headindexcounter;
        headindexcounter++;
        anfang->next=NULL;
    }else{
        struct SearchEntry *zeiger;
        zeiger=anfang;
        while(zeiger->next!=NULL)
        zeiger=zeiger->next;
        if((zeiger->next=malloc(sizeof(struct SearchEntry)))==NULL){
            fprintf(stderr, "Kein Speicherplatz vorhanden für Anfang\n");
            return;
        }
        zeiger=zeiger->next;
        if(TimeStamp!=NULL){
            zeiger->TimeStamp=malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(TimeStamp));
            strcpy(zeiger->TimeStamp, TimeStamp);
        }else{
            strcpy(zeiger->TimeStamp, "0");
        }
        if(IP!=NULL){
            zeiger->IP=malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(IP));
            strcpy(zeiger->IP, IP);
        }else{
            strcpy(zeiger->IP, "0");
        }
        if(Empfaenger!=NULL){
            char *empfaenger=strtok(Empfaenger, ", ");
            zeiger->anfangE=NULL;
            zeiger->nextE=NULL;

            //Here begins the code to put kame a new struct/list inside of the firstlist SearchEntry

            while(empfaenger!=NULL){
                printf("EMPFAENGER: %s\n", empfaenger);
                if(zeiger->anfangE==NULL){
                    if((zeiger->anfangE=malloc(sizeof(struct Empfaenger)))==NULL){
                        fprintf(stderr, "Kein Speicherplatz vorhanden für Anfang\n");
                        return;
                    }
                   zeiger->anfangE->Empfaenger=malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(empfaenger));
                    strcpy(zeiger->anfangE->Empfaenger, empfaenger);
                    printf("zeiger->anfangE->Empfaenger=%s\n", zeiger->anfangE->Empfaenger);
                    zeiger->anfangE->headindex=headindexcounterE;
                    headindexcounterE++;
                    zeiger->anfangE->nextE=NULL;
                    printf("xyz_a!\n");
                }else{
                    printf("abc_b!\n");
                    struct Empfaenger *zeigerE;
                    zeigerE=zeiger->anfangE;
                    while(zeigerE->nextE!=NULL)
                    zeigerE=zeigerE->nextE;
                    if((zeigerE->nextE=malloc(sizeof(struct Empfaenger)))==NULL){
                        fprintf(stderr, "Kein Speicherplatz vorhanden für Anfang\n");
                        return;
                    }
                    zeigerE=zeigerE->nextE;
                    zeigerE->Empfaenger=malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(empfaenger));
                    strcpy(zeigerE->Empfaenger, empfaenger);
                    printf("zeiger->anfangE->Empfaenger=%s\n", zeigerE->Empfaenger);
                    zeigerE->headindex=headindexcounterE;
                    headindexcounterE++;
                    zeigerE->nextE=NULL;
                    printf("xyz_b!\n");
                }
                empfaenger=strtok(0, ", ");
            }
```

//

```
        }else{
            printf("NULL: %s\n", Empfaenger);
            strcpy(zeiger->anfangE->Empfaenger, "NULL");
            zeiger->anfangE->headindex=0;
            zeiger->anfangE->nextE=NULL;
        }
        if(MailId!=NULL){
            zeiger->MailId=malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(MailId));
            strcpy(zeiger->MailId, MailId);
            printf("%s\n", zeiger->MailId);
        }else{
            strcpy(zeiger->MailId, "0");
        }
        printf("y!\n");
        zeiger->headindex=headindexcounter;
        headindexcounter++;
        zeiger->next=NULL;
        printf("stopb!\n");
    }
}
```

And this is the function to read all the Data out of the two lists:

```
void Searchoutput(){
    struct SearchEntry *zeiger=anfang;
    while(zeiger!=NULL){
        printf("%s\n", zeiger->TimeStamp);
        printf("%s\n", zeiger->IP);
        printf("%s\n", zeiger->MailId);
        struct Empfaenger *zeigerE=zeiger->anfangE;
        while(zeigerE!=NULL){
            printf("%s\n", zeigerE->Empfaenger);
            zeigerE=zeigerE->nextE;
        }
        zeiger=zeiger->next;
    }
}
```

The Code To put the Data in the first and second linked list works, and also when I try to read the Data out of the first only, but when I try to read the data out of the first and then inside of the loop also try to read out the data of the second linked list I get a memory access error.
Does anyone know where the problem is? I already tried it out without the part of the second list, because of I know that works.

Comment: Serious? ou dident even indent the code nor have heared about a SSCCE= Do ou really belive, that some one will read this to solve your problem?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know where the Problem with the indentation is, I made id to put the program in 3 parts. I can't put the full program including the main in here, because it will going to be too big for this here. And I really know that this is the only part of my programm which causes the error...

Answer (score 0):

Your memory allocations for strings are wrong, you fail to allocate room for the terminator. This means that every `strcpy()` overwrites random memory, which causes undefined behavior.

These:

```
anfang->TimeStamp=malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(TimeStamp));
anfang->IP=malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(IP));
anfang->MailId=malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(MailId));
```

should be:

```
anfang->TimeStamp = malloc(strlen(TimeStamp) + 1);
anfang->IP = malloc(strlen(IP) + 1);
anfang->MailId = malloc(strlen(MailId) + 1);
```

I removed the pointless scaling by `sizeof(char)`, that's always going to be 1. You should also check the allocations for failure before relying on them having succeeded. Finally the above is quite inefficient since it does three smallish allocations rather than a single large one but perhaps you need them to be independent.

Comment: Yes, I forgot the check, that could it really be, but what do you mean with a single large one, I didn't even heard of this... do you mean that I should rather take a large array for this?

Comment: I checked this now, but the first part where I put the Data for the TimeStamp, the Ip, and MailId inside the first list, does already work. The Problem, where The memory error occurs is the second part which is here the third grey box.